# Database corrupts after many INSERT operations

Tags: php, database, sqlite

My code below is supposed to automate insertion of a CSV into a database. Howvever, if the input file contains more than *10* lines, the database supposedly corrupts with the message, "database disk image is malformated".

```
$db->exec('BEGIN;');
while(!feof($data)) {
    $line = fgets($data);
    $tmp = split(",", $line);

    $query = "INSERT INTO calendar_dates VALUES (
            '$tmp[0]','$tmp[1]',$tmp[2])";

    $db->exec($query);
    if (!$results) {
        exit ("Error<br>");
    }

}

$db->exec('COMMIT;');
```

Comment: Maybe up overload the database system?

Comment: I don't think so. In my EDIT, I detailed that with only 10 queries, the problem occured and I believe sqlite can handle much more...

Comment: Maybe the query sting is too long? I really can't think of anything else. Can we see a file that would crash it?

Comment: The csv file is a simple calendar_dates.txt file in GTFS format (about 13000 rows of data).
Besides, I imported this very same file into an sqlite database via command line and there is no problem at all, but I would like to automate this process in PHP so that I don't have to do it manually...

Comment: Hmmm. That's really weird. I'd file a bug report. Pn the side, how would using PHP help you automate it?

Comment: I mean via a cron job launched on my web server...

Comment: That makes sense. However, considering the bizarity of this situation, can't you automate it with a bash script?

Comment: Well, yes... But I have no idea how it works, could you give some links/tutorials about it?

Comment: Sadly, I don't have much knowledge of bash. However, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886) might help.

Comment: What is your memory usage? Is it possible that your PHP code gets killed after exceeding memory limit? This could explain why db gets corrupted

Comment: I run a memory_get_usage at the beginning and at the end of my script.
Here are the results: 639472 & 3212104.
But, I remember that in the past, I already had memory trouble with another script and PHP mentioned it with some kind of "Out of memory" error. So I don't think that's the case here.